# Quran‘s nature on Earth?

Tags: quran, revelation

How do respond to the people, who compare the revelation/descending of the Quran with their wrong belief of Jesus being the son of God on Earth. How is the nature of the Quran in our Earth? (Sunni view)

Comment: The analogy of „mirrored words“ really solved my confusion, Elhamdulillah.

Answer (score 1):

***The Quran is the direct word of Allah. It is divine, heavenly, and authentic, a miracle come through a normal human, Muhammad ﷺ. whose greatness is based on the greatness of God.***

That is  - in brief - what we say about the nature of the Holy Quran.

In the following, I will try to expose how we can respond to people who compare the revelation/descending of the Quran with Jesus being the son of God on Earth:

**The Quran is sent down as a reliable guidance**

2:2-5

> This is the Book in which there is no doubt, a guide for the
> righteous. Those who believe in the unseen, and perform the prayers,
> and give from what We have provided for them. And those who believe in
> what was revealed to you, and in what was revealed before you, and are
> certain of the Hereafter. These are upon guidance from their Lord.
> These are the successful.

**It is not the first but the last guidance God has conveyed to us through revelation:**

3:3

> He sent down to you the Book with the Truth, confirming what came
> before it; and He sent down the Torah and the Gospel.

4:136

> O you who believe! Believe in God and His messenger, and the Book He
> sent down to His messenger, and the Book He sent down before. Whoever
> rejects God, His angels, His Books, His messengers, and the Last Day,
> has strayed far in error.

**Yes, there is a dispute between those who accept the last Prophet ﷺ and those who deny the last Prophet ﷺ . This i not a reason to quarrel but to compete in doing good:**

2:213

> Humanity used to be one community; then God sent the prophets,
> bringing good news and giving warnings. And He sent down with them the
> Scripture, with the truth, to judge between people regarding their
> differences. But none differed over it except those who were given
> it—after the proofs had come to them—out of mutual envy between them.
> Then God guided those who believed to the truth they had disputed, in
> accordance with His will. God guides whom He wills to a straight  path.

5:48

> And We revealed to you the Book, with truth, confirming the Scripture
> that preceded it, and superseding it. So judge between them according
> to what God revealed, and do not follow their desires if they differ
> from the truth that has come to you. For each of you We have assigned
> a law and a method. Had God willed, He could have made you a single
> nation, but He tests you through what He has given you. So compete in
> righteousness. To God is your return, all of you; then He will inform
> you of what you had disputed.

**The Quran confirms that Jesus is the Messiah, made through the Holy Spirit and the Prophet who is one of the nearest to God:**

3:45

> The Angels said, “O Mary, God gives you good news of a Word from Him.
> His name is the Messiah, Jesus, son of Mary, well-esteemed in this
> world and the next, and one of the nearest. He will speak to the
> people from the crib, and in adulthood, and will be one of the
> righteous.”

3:59

> The likeness of Jesus in God’s sight is that of Adam: He created him
> from dust, then said to him, “Be,” and he was.

19:16

> And mention in the Scripture Mary, when she withdrew from her people
> to an eastern location. She screened herself away from them, and We
> sent to her Our spirit, and He appeared to her as an immaculate human.

**In the Message of the Quran God says that it is an error to assume that Jesus is a Son of God like the polytheists thought that their deities had sons with humans.**

*Many Christians will say that this is not their belief. It is good so.*

4:171-173

> O People of the Scripture! Do not exaggerate in your religion, and do
> not say about God except the truth. The Messiah, Jesus, the son of
> Mary, is the Messenger of God, and His Word that He conveyed to Mary,
> and a Spirit from Him. So believe in God and His messengers, and do
> not say, “Three.” Refrain—it is better for you. God is only one God.
> Glory be to Him—that He should have a son. To Him belongs everything
> in the heavens and the earth, and God is a sufficient Protector. The
> Messiah does not disdain to be a servant of God, nor do the favoured
> angels. Whoever disdains His worship, and is too arrogant — He will
> round them up to Himself altogether. But as for those who believe and
> do good works, He will pay them their wages in full, and will increase
> His grace for them. But as for those who disdain and are too proud, He
> will punish them with an agonizing punishment. And they will find for
> themselves, apart from God, no lord and no saviour.

**The Quran also corrects Christians, saying that it is only God to whom we should pray and whom we should worship, not to Jesus or his mother Mary.**

5:116

> And God will say, “O Jesus son of Mary, did you say to the people,
> `Take me and my mother as gods rather than God?'“ He will say, “Glory
> be to You! It is not for me to say what I have no right to. Had I said
> it, You would have known it. You know what is in my soul, and I do not
> know what is in your soul. You are the Knower of the hidden. I only
> told them what You commanded me: that you shall worship God, my Lord
> and your Lord. And I was a witness over them while I was among them;
> but when You took me to Yourself, you became the Watcher over them—You
> are Witness over everything. If You punish them, they are Your
> servants; but if You forgive them, You are the Mighty and Wise.”

*This is completely in accordance to the teachings of Jesus ﷺ who taught to pray (Matthew 6:9)*

> Our Father...

*meaning to God, to whom we should have confidence like a child has to its father.*

The Holy Quran is not a book of an idle person who wanted to compete with Jesus ﷺ . It is a revelation of God. Muhammad  ﷺ did not compete with Jesus. The question who of them is the greater prophet is idle. This is not written in the Message God sent to Muhammad ﷺ, nor has the Prophet himself ever uttered alike.

The Quran is an excellent and comprehensive guidance, given to Muhammad for the Arabs in their language to understand and bend to the One and Only God, giving clear rules not only for the Jews but universally - as it had not been clear to the non-Jewish Christians which rules would apply to them -

*And it is a marvellous book*

We may compete in goodness. But if we only want to be better than the other, or even childishly want to prove that we have a better prophet than the others, we lose. Good is who serves the Word of God.

Comment: Thanks for the work and the first part was very well written, but I disagree with the last part. The prophets are same in delivering the message, but not same in status as Abraham (Peace be upon him) and Muhammad (Peace and Blessings be upon him) are both called „Friend of Allah“, which makes them more honoured. Every prophet has its own blessing (For example Allah talking directly to Moses etc). The Prophet Muhammad (Peace and Blessings be upon him) lead the prophets in prayer in his night journey, which also symbolizes his higher status.

Comment: It is not for a believing man or woman—when Allah and His Messenger decree a matter—to have any other choice in that matter. Indeed, whoever disobeys Allah and His Messenger has clearly gone ˹far˺ astray. (Quran 33:36) With all the respect, I only wish the best for people, but your belief is not right, every believer is obliged to follow the law of Muhammad (Peace and Blessings be upon him) as it is clear in the Quran and Sunnah in many incidents in his life, where Jews and Christians were commanded to follow him.

Comment: The people should not make themselves more knowledgeable than 1400 years of great scholarship in Islam by their own reading. It is undeniably in (Sunni) Islam, that the law of the final prophet is to be implemented in our lifes. If I want to know more about our organism, I will read books by experts and if I want to be religious in Islam, I adhere to the knowledgeable scholars, as I am not a qualified student for more. I wanted that this should be clear, so Muslims should not get confused by the last part of your answer or your narrative.

Comment: How can qur'an be the word of G-d if G-d does not have vocal cords?

Comment: I have written this answer in the mind to speak and answer to a Christian.